# how to add custom keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I did a simple application.

My application contains 10 Text fields.

what i need is i need to hide default keypad i place manual keys [like this](http://b.imagehost.org/download/0994/keypad)

How can i done this keys works as a keypad to my app.

can any one pls post some code or link.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a [KeyPad](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/KeyPad), that is easy to customize via its delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a view with 10 buttons and assign action for each of them.

In the didBeginEditing method diss the keyboard using,

```
[textField resignFirstResponder]
[yourKeyboard show];
```

And i think apple will reject the applications using custom keyboard

Answer (score 1):

There is a complete thread about that [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-custimize-keyboard.html)
It has a tutorial, lots of comments, sample code and project, everything you need is there. (Is quite long though)

You basically create a view with your buttons for example and 
In iOS3.2 and above you can use inputView property of your textField.
In early iOS versions you have to do a trick (add your keyboard as a subview of UIKeyboard) that is also written in the link.

If you need more advanced stuff than simple numbers, you probably want to look at [UIKeyInput](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITextInput](http://17.254.2.129/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocols.

Hope it helps